# How to delete break in table line

Tags: tables

I have a simple table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{nr fragmentu} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{wymiary [cm]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{wymiary fragmentu} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{dł.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{szer.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{powierzchnia} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{dł.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{szer.} \\
    \hline
    1     & 6,8   & 4,9   & 33,6  & 7,0   & 11,8 \\
    2     & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,1  & 10,0  & 4,5 \\
    3     & 3,4   & 2,4   & 7,9   & 6,5   & 3,5 \\
    4     & 7,8   & 5,5   & 43,3  & 12,5  & 10,1 \\
    5     & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,4  & 9,7   & 4,9 \\
    6     & 3,6   & 2,5   & 9,1   & 5,5   & 4,8 \\
    7     & 3,3   & 2,3   & 7,8   & 6,7   & 3,3 \\
    8     & 6,2   & 4,4   & 27,2  & 12,5  & 6,2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:tabela3}%
\end{table}%
```

and I don't understand why I have line break in first row like on the picture:
[image: line break]

How can a merge horizontal line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You're getting the interruptions in the vertical lines because you're using the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package inappropriately. The user guide of that package states unmistakably and unequivocally that if you want to use the package's macros, you should not employ any vertical lines. Conversely, if you feel you simply must use vertical lines, don't use the `booktabs` package. There is no in-between compromise.

Comment: For the table at hand, if you decide that having continuous vertical lines is more important to you than having a pleasing table layout, you would need to replace `\cmidrule{2-6}` with `\cline{2-6}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've noted in a comment, don't employ the `booktabs` package (and its `\cmidrule` macro) if you (a) want to employ vertical lines and (b) insist on the vertical lines not suffer interruptions. Just replace `\cmidrule{2-6}` with `\cline`.

But do please give some thought to how you could improve the "look" of the table significantly by getting rid of all vertical lines andy by using few but well-spaced horizontal lines (by using the macros of the `booktabs` package).

I would also like to encourage you to improve the table's appearance -- and hence the likelihood that your readers will actually linger and take in the *contents* of the table -- by aligning the numbers in the five data columns on their respective decimal markers. This may be done with the help of the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. The package also lets you specify which type of decimal marker -- period or comma -- you'd like to use without editing the numbers directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % not needed
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption\strut}
  \label{tab:tabela3}
  
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]} *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]} @{} }
    \toprule
    nr fragmentu & \multicolumn{3}{c}{wymiary [cm]} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{wymiary} \\
    & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{fragmentu} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
    & {dł.} & {szer.} & {powierzchnia} & {dł.} & {szer.} \\
    \midrule
    1     & 6,8   & 4,9   & 33,6  & 7,0   & 11,8 \\
    2     & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,1  & 10,0  & 4,5  \\
    3     & 3,4   & 2,4   & 7,9   & 6,5   & 3,5  \\
    4     & 7,8   & 5,5   & 43,3  & 12,5  & 10,1 \\ \addlinespace
    5     & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,4  & 9,7   & 4,9  \\
    6     & 3,6   & 2,5   & 9,1   & 5,5   & 4,8  \\
    7     & 3,3   & 2,3   & 7,8   & 6,7   & 3,3  \\
    8     & 6,2   & 4,4   & 27,2  & 12,5  & 6,2  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for help and advices

Comment: Thank you also for `{newtxtext,newtxmath}` package

Comment: Just for a nicer look, it would be better if the first cell `nr fragmentu` was centered

Comment: @Chey - I think you know how to work the `\multirow` command. :-) (FWIW, I actually disagree with the view that the header would look better if it were centered vertically across the three rows. One can't argue about taste, though, right?)

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @Mico answer (+1), but columns are locked in "jail" of vertical lines and for horizontal lines are used `Xhline` defined in the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                                 {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1,
             output-decimal-marker={,}
             }   
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \centering
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:tabela3}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c |*{2}{S[table-format=1.1]|}
                        *{3}{S|} }
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{nr.\\ fragmentu}} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{wymiary [cm]}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{wymiary\\ fragmentu}}    \\
    \cline{2-6} 
    & \mcc{dł.} & \mcc{szer.} & \mcc{powierzchnia} & \mcc{dł.} &  \mcc{szer.} \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
1   & 6,8   & 4,9   & 33,6  &  7,0  & 11,8 \\
2   & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,1  & 10,0  &  4,5 \\
3   & 3,4   & 2,4   &  7,9  &  6,5  &  3,5 \\
4   & 7,8   & 5,5   &  43,3 & 12,5  & 10,1 \\
5   & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,4  &  9,7  &  4,9 \\
6   & 3,6   & 2,5   &  9,1  &  5,5  &  4,8 \\
7   & 3,3   & 2,3   &  7,8  &  6,7  &  3,3 \\
8   & 6,2   & 4,4   & 27,2  & 12,5  &  6,2 \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** As suggested @Mico in his comment, decimal dots are now replaced with decimal comma.

**Addendum**
Your table without vertical lines but with use of the `tabularray` package and `X` column type. For fun and exercise, but you may liked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2,
             output-decimal-marker={,},
             }
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:tabela3}%
\begin{tblr}{width=3\linewidth/4,
             colspec = {c *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.1}]}
                          *{3}{X[c, si]}
                        },
             rowsep=1pt,
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    {nr.\\ fragmentu}  
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{wymiary\\ {[cm]} }}}
            &       &       & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  {{{wymiary\\fragm}}}%{{{\\ tu}}}
                                    &               \\
    \cmidrule[r=-0.5]{2-4}
    \cmidrule[l=-0.5]{5-6}
    & {{{dł.}}}
            & {{{szer.}}}
                    & {{{powier.}}}
                            & {{{dł.}}}
                                    &  {{{szer.}}}  \\
    \midrule
1   & 6,8   & 4,9   & 33,6  &  7,0  & 11,8          \\
2   & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,1  & 10,0  &  4,5          \\
3   & 3,4   & 2,4   &  7,9  &  6,5  &  3,5          \\
4   & 7,8   & 5,5   &  43,3 & 12,5  & 10,1          \\
5   & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,4  &  9,7  &  4,9          \\
6   & 3,6   & 2,5   &  9,1  &  5,5  &  4,8          \\
7   & 3,3   & 2,3   &  7,8  &  6,7  &  3,3          \\
8   & 6,2   & 4,4   & 27,2  & 12,5  &  6,2          \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. :-) I think you should provide the option `output-decimal-marker={,}`, though, as the OP's locale would favor the use of `,` (comma) as the output decimal marker.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! You are right.  I will correct ASAP.

Comment: I add my approvation :-) :-) :-) :-) :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much! You make my day more bright :-)

Comment: The 2nd table looks much prettier than the first one.

Comment: @Imran, of course. People say, that such design is "professional". It is almost the same as in the accepted answer, but table code is quite different [therefore I mentioned that addendum is for fun and exercise ;-) ]

Answer (score 3):

For information. The vertical rules of `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` are compatible with the rules of `booktabs`. However, as said in other answers, the best design is probably with the rules of `booktabs` in the spirit of `booktabs` (without vertical rules).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \Block{2-1}{nr fragmentu} & \Block{1-3}{wymiary [cm]} &&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{wymiary fragmentu} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} & dł. & szer. & powierzchnia & dł. & szer. \\
    \hline
    1     & 6,8   & 4,9   & 33,6  & 7,0   & 11,8 \\
    2     & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,1  & 10,0  & 4,5 \\
    3     & 3,4   & 2,4   & 7,9   & 6,5   & 3,5 \\
    4     & 7,8   & 5,5   & 43,3  & 12,5  & 10,1 \\
    5     & 4,8   & 3,4   & 16,4  & 9,7   & 4,9 \\
    6     & 3,6   & 2,5   & 9,1   & 5,5   & 4,8 \\
    7     & 3,3   & 2,3   & 7,8   & 6,7   & 3,3 \\
    8     & 6,2   & 4,4   & 27,2  & 12,5  & 6,2 \\
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}%
  \label{tab:tabela3}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]