# Complete vertical lines in LaTeX table

Tags: tables

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Hoja1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{5.215em}|}{Case Study} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.57em}|}{H2O inlet (m/s)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.5em}|}{CO2 inlet (m/s)} \\
    \midrule
    1     & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{0.05} & 0.75 \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}    2     &       & 1 \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}    3     &       & 1.5 \\
    \midrule
    4     & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{0.075} & 0.75 \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}    5     &       & 1 \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}    6     &       & 1.5 \\
    \midrule
    7     & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{0.1} & 0.75 \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}    8     &       & 1 \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}    9     &       & 1.5 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Produces the table shown in the picture.
[image]

I would like to complete the vertical lines. What can I do?

Comment: please see the `booktabs` package documentation it explicitly documents that vertical rules should not be used with the package.

Comment: however see this duplicate question for answers using the nicematrix package https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624792/1090

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete break in table line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623882/how-to-delete-break-in-table-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't use `booktabs` at all and switch to `\hline` and `\cline`. Note your auto-generated markup is a bit overly complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Case Study & H2O inlet (m/s) & CO2 inlet (m/s) \\
\hline
1     & \multirow{3}{*}{0.05} & 0.75 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}    2     &       & 1 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}    3     &       & 1.5 \\
\hline
4     & \multirow{3}{*}{0.075} & 0.75 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}    5     &       & 1 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}    6     &       & 1.5 \\
\hline
7     & \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.75 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}    8     &       & 1 \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}    9     &       & 1.5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do want to use `booktabs` you really should remove the vertical lines and go with something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Case Study & H2O inlet (m/s) & CO2 inlet (m/s) \\
\midrule
1     & \multirow{3}{*}{0.05} & 0.75 \\
2     &       & 1 \\
3     &       & 1.5 \\
\midrule
4     & \multirow{3}{*}{0.075} & 0.75 \\
5     &       & 1 \\
6     &       & 1.5 \\
\midrule
7     & \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.75 \\
8     &       & 1 \\
9     &       & 1.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `booktabs` manual says **"never, ever use vertical rules"**.

You can, however, reduce the spaces in the vertical rules along the lines of:

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0.1ex}  % default 0.4ex
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0.1ex}  % default 0.65ex
```

Doing this, of course defeats the purpose of the `booktabs` package, but that is up to you

Answer (score 0):

Vertical lines at packages `nicetabular` and `tabularray` works well with rules defined in the `booktabs` package. For example, MWE using `tabularray` and `S` column type in columns with numbers, is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{chemfig}  % if needed
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{per-mode = symbol}
    \centering
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{2-Y}, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[c,m, wd=5em] 
                            Q[c,m, si={table-format=1.3}, wd=5em]
                            Q[c,m, si={table-format=1.2}, wd=5em]}
                 }
    \toprule
{Case\\ Study}
    & {{{ \ce{H2O} inlet\\ (\si{\meter\per\second}) }}}
        & {{{\ce{CO2} inlet\\ (\si{\meter\per\second})}}}   \\
1   & \SetCell[r=3]{m}  0.05    & 0.75  \\
2   &                           & 1     \\
3   &                           & 1.5   \\
4   & \SetCell[r=3]{m}  0.075   & 0.75  \\
5   &                           & 1     \\
6   &                           & 1.5   \\
7   & \SetCell[r=3]{m}  0.1     & 0.75  \\
8   &                           & 1     \\
9   &                           & 1.5   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]